# Or condition in element_to_be_clickable selenium/python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

Looking for idea how to resolve my problem with "or" statement inside .element_to_be_clickable function in python-selenium.
I want to my script click one of few (elements)buttons if one of them are clickable(I want to list them in this method with full xpath.
For now it works only for one `button(/html/body/button[1]`). Someone may help me?

```
while True:
    try:
        button = WebDriverWait(window, timeout=(random.randint(5, 10)), poll_frequency=0.2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/button[1]"))).click()
        break # leave while loop
    except TimeoutException:
        window.refresh()
```

Tried like that but didn't work:

```
while True:
    try:
        button = WebDriverWait(window, timeout=(random.randint(5, 10)), poll_frequency=0.2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/button[1]" or "/html/body/button[2]"))).click()
        break # leave while loop
    except TimeoutException:
        window.refresh()
```

Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 0):

There is [**any_of**](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.all_of) [`expected_condition`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.html#all_of).
As per documentation:

```
An expectation that any of multiple expected conditions is true.
Equivalent to a logical 'OR'.
Returns results of the first matching condition, or False if none do.
```

The example of use of it looks like:

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.any_of(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/button[1]")),
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/button[2]"))
    )
)
```

**UPD**
If I understand correctly the documentation I linked to above, the code block above returns a Boolean, not a web element object. So, you can not click it directly. To perform a click I'd suggest the following code:

```py
if WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.any_of(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/button[1]")), EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/button[2]")))):
    try:
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/button[1]").click()
    except:
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/button[2]").click()
```

Explanations:
Code flow will go into the `if` block in case the function returned `True`. This means at least one of the elements found clickable.
So, we can try clicking the first element.
In case it is clickable - the click will be done.
Otherwise the second element will be clicked.

Comment: Thanks for answer @Prophet

after implement your idea Im getting error 'function' object has no attribute 'click'
Any workaround in this?

Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'function' object has no attribute 'click'
  File "C:\Users\xx\visual projects\orcheck.py", line 32, in <module>
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/button[1]")).click(),

Comment: Still not works, it's only clicking first argument (not even checking second one)

Comment: That's strange... Unfortunately, I can't debug this issue since I don't have the conditions for that, the page you are working on

Comment: try on this html code:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The button enabled attribute</h1>

<button disabled onclick="location.href = 'www.google.com';" id="myButton" class="not works" >Click me</button>
<h1>The button disabled attribute</h1>

<button  onclick="location.href = 'www.youtube.com';" id="myButton2" class="works" >Click me</button>
</body>
</html>

Comment: It should be real web site, not just a piece of HTML.

Comment: It's enough for testing because this piece of HTML is redirecting to youtube or google after button.click thus you can check in URL if bot clicked button